# Not able to install nvidia's BINARY DRIVERS

Tags: drivers, nvidia

following was done :-

```
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
sudo shutdown -r now
sudo service lightdm stop
ctrl-alt-f1
cd /home/vinod/Downloads/
./vin.run
```

`vin.run` is the file downloaded from the nvidia website for my gt 630

the installation log file says this :-

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Fri Nov  7 23:22:24 2014
installer version: 295.53
```

PATH: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

nvidia-installer command line:

```
./nvidia-installer

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> License accepted.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 295.53.
-> Running distribution scripts
   executing: '/usr/lib/nvidia/pre-install'...
-> done.
-> The distribution-provided pre-install script failed!  Continue installation anyway? (Answer: Yes)
-> Performing CC sanity check with CC="cc".
-> Performing CC version check with CC="cc".
ERROR: The kernel header file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build/include/linux/version.h' does not exist.  The most likely reason for this is that the kernel source files in '/lib/modules/3.13.0-39-generic/build' have not been configured.
ERROR: Installation has failed.
.....
```

someone help me out :(

Comment: When you installed nvidia-current, you installed the nvidia from the repository. But then you tried to install the downloaded version. They almost always conflict and now you probably need to totally purge all nvidia and reinstall from repository. http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers AND: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the Nvidia Drivers from the repositories as they tend to work better with the releases than the binary files from Nvidia, unless you want to run your system at the bleeding edge. If so, you might want to consider adding the Xorg-edgers PPA, which can provide that bleeding edge experience with purpose built .debs for install.

As to your particular issue, do you have DKMS and/or the kernel headers installed locally? If you do not, you will need to install them in order to build the kernel modules for the driver and have it installed successfully.

HTH. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Install and uninstall these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms gcc build-essential linux-source linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

The dkms package will ensure the driver is carried over if you upgrade your kernel.

Then,

```
sudo chmod +x /home/vinod/Downloads/vin.run
```

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, login with your username and password and execute the following commands to run the installer:

```
cd /home/vinod/Downloads
sudo ./vin.run
```

I believe you forgot sudo earlier and that is probably why the pre-install-script failed but you might not have installed dkms and you will need that.

Follow the instructions. If there are errors, they should be listed in the output on-screen. Reboot for the changes to take effect.